# Most used convention about Christoffel symbols

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

Just a simple question: what is the most used form for Christoffel symbols, (1) or (2), see below:

(1) $$\Gamma_{ij}^{k} = g^{kl}\Gamma_{lij}$$

and then, we have: $$\Gamma_{lij}=\Gamma_{lji}$$

(2) $$\Gamma_{ij}^{k} = g^{kl}\Gamma_{ilj}$$

and then, we have: $$\Gamma_{ilj}=\Gamma_{jli}~?$$

Indeed, I saw these 2 kinds of expression and I would like to know if there is a general convention about this.

**UPDATE 1 :**

As suggested by Ben Crowell,

the issue is to know if $\Gamma^{a}_{bc}$ represents conventionally to $\Gamma^a{}_{bc}$ or $\Gamma_b{}^a{}_c$ ? I just want to know what's the most used form.

**UPDATE 2 :** Please, could anyone indicate me the convention to take about my issue (since my teacher is taking the convention $\Gamma_{ij}^{k} = g^{kl}\Gamma_{ilj}$ and I am not sure this convention is common) ?

Comment: Where did you encounter (2)?

Comment: @Qmechanic : into the lectures of my teacher

Comment: FWIW, since the Christoffel symbols have 3 indices, there is in principle also a third possibility $\Gamma_{ab}{}^{c}$.

Comment: -@Qmechanic . Do you want to say that (1) convention is the standard rule, I mean the most used ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. Is the following correct? You seem to be assuming (correctly, AFAIK) that the mixed form of the symbol (with one upper and two lower indices) is standardized, but you're asking about the totally covariant form (three lower indices). The question is essentially whether, for purposes of raising and lowering indices, the symbol $\Gamma^{a}_{bc}$ is to be interpreted as $\Gamma^a{}_{bc}$, or as $\Gamma_b{}^a{}_c$. Is that right?

Comment: -@BenCrowell. Yes, the issue is to know if $\Gamma^{a}_{bc}$ represents conventionally to $\Gamma^a{}_{bc}$ or $\Gamma_b{}^a{}_c$ ? I just want to know what's the most used form. thanks

Comment: @youpilat13: I suggest you edit the question to say that.

Comment: There's two issues here: (a) You really cannot raise or lower indices on the Christoffel symbols, they are not tensors. (b) If you want, you could think of the 'proper' index placement $\Gamma_{\mu\phantom{\nu}\rho}^{\phantom{\mu}\nu}$, in analogy to the gauge potentials in e.g. QCD. However, because of (A), that doesn't get you very far in terms of computations.